# Race Results and Points

Tags: php, sql

I am in desperate need of help and hoping someone can assist me. I'm new to PHP and SQL and I'm trying to create a Cross Country app so that when a runner crosses the finish line their time is recorded in an SQL database. The part that I can't figure out is how to convert placing to points so I can determine which house (team) is the winner ie

```
1st place - 15 points
2nd place - 12 points
3rd place - 10 points
4th place - 8 points
5th place - 7 points
6th place - 6 points
7th place - 5 points
8th place - 4 points
9th place - 3 points
10th place - 2 points
11th onwards - 1 point
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKApy.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help and thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please include some rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Can you provide your database schema ?